# Which API does Marketing Cloud Connect call on Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We're trying to access the Salesforce 'Activity' Object from Marketing Cloud for it to sync, but can't;

Does anyone know which API is used by MC Connect?

If it's the ui api this is an expected behavior:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm

Thoughts on how to access this object?

Answer (score 1):

The last update to the [API version](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_august_2019_mcc_api_compatibility.htm&type=5) was to v46.

> Marketing Cloud Connect is now compatible with version 46.0 of the Sales Cloud and Service Cloud API. Objects that are available in the Sales Cloud and Service Cloud API version 46.0 are now available to Marketing Cloud Connect, Data Sync, and Journey Builder.
>
> Objects that are available in the Sales Cloud and Service Cloud API version 46.0 are now available to Marketing Cloud Connect, Data Sync, and Journey Builder.

Comment: thanks @EazyE, it pointed me to the right direction, though unclear if the version compatibility refers to the UI API or the SOAP API? My guess is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for future reference to anyone who is interested in the question.

The links in the documentation lead to the **SOAP API**.

Currently (April 2021) it's version 46.0 as @EazyE mentioned, although the latest version of the API is now v.51.0

The direct link to this API capabilities is here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm

To viably answer this question in the future you'd want to verify:

1. The Marketing Cloud Connect API Compatibility here:
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_august_2019_mcc_api_compatibility.htm&type=5

(Search for Marketing Cloud Connect API in the searchbox)

Then,

2. Go to the first link and select the version you need at the top.

Also,
this answer will not be complete without providing a way to know which API version is used on the CRM side, which is found here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334996&type=1&mode=1